# Python - use the print in the next code

Tags: python, pandas, printing, append

This code generates the columns with missing's (it is ok)

```
for a in data.columns:
    if data[a].isnull().any() == True:
        print (a)
```

and now I want to use the columns of the previous code to apply to the following code

```
data[a].isnull().sum()
```

but the 'a' does not save the column names with missing's, is just the name of the last column. I need to use something like b=print (a) and doing the append do a list but I can´t find the right code.

Comment: Honestly this question isn't that clear, please consider editing it. If you need to save the items that trigger the conditional create something like a list then append to it.

Comment: I dont excatly understand what you want to do.. Get the number of empty collumns in data?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Don't ask about appending values to a list when in reality you want to do something else. If I understand the problem correctly, you want to count the NaN values in each column?

Comment: yes I want to get the number of empty columns in data but i just want to use the columns that are print in the first code, I don't want to see the others columns.
I have this question on this code but I also want to understand
how can I use the printing variables in other's codes because I need to use in more codes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I suggest you clean up your question and provide a [mcve]. Show an example of a dataframe with some NaN values and the result you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for.

```
res = [data[a].isnull().sum() for a in data.columns]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will provide a list of columns has nulls/NaNs

```
null_index = df.isnull().any()
a= null_index[null_index==True].index.tolist()
```

`a` will have a list of all the column names that has nulls in the column.